# Add loop counter to CSV data in jMeter

Tags: loops, csv, jmeter

I am doing some tests on `jMeter`, and I have a scenario which involves looping twice the requests. I am exporting data to CSV format and I need to have a field which indicates me (for each sample), at which loop we are. I currently have a Counter element used for an If Controller, if this could help.

Any advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by using [Flexible File Writer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) plugin, which permits to write more kinds of data to the CSV file.

Before using Flexible File Writer, I told jMeter to sample my variable through its preferences, doing so:

- open jmeter.properties file
- look for `sample_variables`
- decomment it
- add your variables names

This should tell jMeter to sample your variable for each sample it takes. Then, within Flexible File Writer, you can refer to that variable via `variable#N`, where `N` is its number in the sampled variables list.

Hope this will be helpful to someone, I found many people had problems doing such things.